# Make scrollable View of window using .xml file : Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

If there are many control in a window which can not appear at same time on window. There may be an option to show them to use view as scrollable, but I don't know how to use it. In my design 5 Edittext in horizontal view and two buttons in vertical view. how can I manage them?

Comment: could you post your layout.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout01">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">


        <EditText android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:minHeight="100dip"></EditText>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText02" android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText01" android:minHeight="100dip"></EditText>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText03" android:layout_below="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText02" android:minHeight="100dip"></EditText>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText04" android:layout_below="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/EditText04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText03" android:minHeight="100dip"></EditText>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText05" android:layout_below="@+id/EditText04"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/EditText05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText04"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText04"></EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip" android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button android:id="@+id/allow" android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Allow"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/deny" android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Deny"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:minHeight="100dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar2Xg.png)

Comment: Yes I want the same. But problem is going same. All 5 EditTexts shows properly but buttons not appearing on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you mean, but you can wrap al your controls in a RelativeLayout.
Then you can bound your RelativeLayout with a ScrollView.